# Rails assignment on a one-to-one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Alright, so I'm trying to connect a Profile object to a Session object through a one to one relationship. The way I understand it is if I have the relationship set up properly, the following is equivalent (please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
@my_session << @my_profile

@my_session.profile = @my_profile

@my_session.profile_id = @my_profile.id
```

I  have the following set up in my models folder

**profile.rb:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :session
```

**session.rb:**

```
 class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    # I tried this without foreign_key also, it works the same
    belongs_to :profile, :foreign_key => 'profile_id'
```

And in my database tables, session has profile_id in it

Doing the following two commands in my rails console works fine:

```
@my_session.profile = @my_profile

@my_session.profile_id = @my_profile.id
```

However, whenever I try to do the following:

```
@my_session << @my_profile
```

I get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<Session:0x00000004a26198>
from /.../rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

Is this some sort of problem with how I have rails setup or something?  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a `has_one` association on an ActiveRecord model it gains the following methods:

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```

Which does not include the shovel operator `<<` thus your error that `<<` is undefined in this case.  It's not a configuration problem.  Looks like your config is working fine. Here's the Rails guide with the specific details

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

The `<<` shovel operator is defined along with all these other methods when you include a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` on a model:

```
collection(force_reload = false)
collection<<(object, ...)
collection.delete(object, ...)
collection.destroy(object, ...)
collection=(objects)
collection_singular_ids
collection_singular_ids=(ids)
collection.clear
collection.empty?
collection.size
collection.find(...)
collection.where(...)
collection.exists?(...)
collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)
collection.create(attributes = {})
collection.create!(attributes = {})
```

Here's the details:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Comment: Okay, so what you're saying is that if I do a 1-1 relationship I shouldn't be able to use <<, and must use one of the 2 options I have working, or the create_association, or build_association?

Comment: Yes. In ruby the << operator is generally used to shovel something into a collection.  So for a has_many you can think of pushing another object into the list of  foo.somethings ( via magic ), but with a has_one there's no collection of objects it's just 1 so it's a single assignment so a collection type operator doesn't make sense there

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No problem.  I'd write it this way `@my_session.profile = @my_profile` personally.  Then use the shovel for a hypothetical has_many like this  `@my_profile.favorites << new_favorite_obj`